# How to change mouse speed - isn't shown in settings for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mouse, system-settings

I just installed 16.04 but I don't see how I can change the mouse speed.
All settings shows is a control for changing double speed click.
[image]

Comment: maybe that will help https://patrickmn.com/aside/lowering-gaming-mouse-sensitivity-in-ubuntu-9-10/

Comment: tried that @tso but it's not changing the speed

Answer (score 0):

### Use xset

to see the current speed:

```
$ xset q | grep -A 1 Pointer

  Pointer Control:
    acceleration:  5/1    threshold:  5
```

To speed the mouse up a bit I used:

```
xset m 5/1 3
```